# Is $({-\pi})^{-\pi}$ complex?

Tags: number-theory

How does one know, if a negative irrational number raised to itself is complex ? Here $({-\pi})^{-\pi}$.

In the case of rational numbers, its very simple. Taking the rational number to be $-x$ , the value becomes $({-x})^{-x}$ . We can represent $x$ to be in the form ${\frac pq}$ where $p$ is an integer and $q$ is a natural number. Then we can determine if $({-x})^{-x}$ is complex by the odd and even properties of $p$ and $q$ (Its complex if q is even and p is odd).  However an irrational number cannot be represented in such a form. That's where I'm stumped.

Comment: This seems to be about $(-\pi)^{-\pi}$, right?

Comment: Yes. Thats right

Comment: PARI outputs $$-0.024756771723269689155891903734911939129 + 0.011801309128026236588593998536287631910*I$$

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes" :-).

Comment: But how did you know that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant complex, I'll make the edit

Comment: You can use $-1=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$ - note that the logarithm function on complex numbers has many branches (hence the $2n$ here) and you will therefore get multiple possible values of the power. Choosing a principal branch for the logarithm gets you a single value, but loses the familiar properties of powers.

Comment: You have to specify your definition of $(-\pi)^{-\pi}$. What you wrote is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us express the number as a complex logarithm.
$$ 
(-\pi)^{-\pi} = \frac{1}{(-\pi)^\pi} = \frac{1}{e^{\log\left[(-\pi)^\pi\right]}} 
$$
Then use the properties of the logarithm:
$$ 
(-\pi)^{-\pi} = \frac{1}{e^{\pi\log(-\pi)}} 
$$
The complex logarithm of $-\pi$ is the solution of:
$$
e^{\log (-\pi)} = -\pi
$$
that is easy to find:
$$ 
\log (-\pi) = \log \pi + i \pi
$$
So we find:
$$ 
(-\pi)^{-\pi} = \frac{1}{e^{\pi(\log \pi + i \pi)}} 
$$
With simple calculations:
$$ 
(-\pi)^{-\pi} = e^{-\pi \log \pi} e^{-i \pi^2}
$$
The first exponential is real, the second is complex, so the result is complex.